# Criar Pastas C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Gostaria de fazer o seguinte.

Criar três pastas uma dentro da outra no `"c:/"`. Os nomes delas serão designados por `textboxes` e na última, criar um arquivo `.doc` pegando o valores de `textboxes`.

---

É para windows forms application.

Eu tentei:

```
string folder = @"C:\folder"; //nome do diretorio a ser criado
folder = textBox1.Text;
//Se o diretório não existir...

if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
{

 //Criamos um com o nome folder
 Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

}
```

Minha dúvida é como criar umas pastas dentro das outras! Uma eu consegui criar. Também precisa ser em um caminho específico `@"C:\folder"`. Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Poste o que já fez e qual é sua dúvida.

Comment: Qual o tipo do projeto? ASP.NET Web Forms? MVC? Windows Forms?

Answer (score 4):

Para criar os diretórios, basta criar o ultimo diretório que os outros níveis são criados automaticamente, você pode usar o método `Directory.CreateDirectory()`, conforme demonstrado abaixo:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        // Specify the directory you want to manipulate.
        string path = @"c:\MyDir1\MyDir2\MyDir3\";

        try 
        {
            // Determine whether the directory exists.
            if (Directory.Exists(path)) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That path exists already.");
                return;
            }

            // Try to create the directory.
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            Console.WriteLine("The directory was created successfully at {0}.", Directory.GetCreationTime(path));

            // Delete the directory.
            di.Delete();
            Console.WriteLine("The directory was deleted successfully.");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        } 
        finally {}
    }
}
```

Exemplo extraído da documentação Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Como ele criar as 3 pasta ai designado por textboxes e na ultima criar um arquivo doc ?

Comment: O Código acima é sobre a criação das pastas, agora sobre a criação do doc, o @Rafael Ferreira tem que postar como ele ira criar o documento, pois existem inúmeras maneiras de se fazer isso, acho que o ideal é ele criar outra pergunta sobre como criar o arquivo .doc.